# Testing babel transpiler script

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for scripts to run through my babel transpiler to prove that it works for es6 and es5.  I've seen https://github.com/michaelficarra/everything.js/blob/master/es2015-script.js but am wondering if there are more things like it.

Comment: You cannot prove by example.

Comment: You're trying to prove that the babel transpiler works?

Comment: I'm having to execute the compiler within java code and to get over the 64K limit I think I'll need to break it up into a few methods which seems somewhat complicated.